# PStree with memory use?

Tags: top, ps

Is there any utility out there for linux that will give me a PStree with memory use per process?

I guess it's possible in theory to grab a pstree with pids, then comb ps itself for the memory use for that pid and merge them together via code, but I would be amazed if someone hasn't done this already before I reinvent the wheel.

Google is failing me, unless I am searching poorly.

Comment: Have you tried `htop` in tree mode?

Comment: htop does not have a "run once" batch mode unfortunately, interactive only